# Using checkboxes in a belongs to and has one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, associations

On the "show" page of my "Account" model I a have a "Checklist" model. I want to be able to check on/off the each of the boolean values on the checklist within the account's show page.
I'm getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Accounts#show
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

- app/models/account.rb

  ```
  class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :checklist
  end
  ```
- app/models/checklist.rb

  ```
  class Checklist < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :account
    belongs_to :user

    validates :account_id, :presence => true
    validates :user_id, :presence => true
  end
  ```
- app/models/user.rb

  ```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :checklists
  end
  ```
- app/controllers/account_controller.rb

  ```
  class AccountController < ApplicationController
    def show
      @account = Account.find(params[:id])
      @checklist = @account.checklist
    end
  end
  ```
- app/views/account/show.html.erb

  ```
  <% simple_form_for(@checklist) do |checklist| %>
    <div>
      <%= checklist.user.email %>
      <div class="pull-right">
        <%= checklist.created_at.strftime("%b. %d %Y") %>
      </div></br>
      <ul>
        <li><%= checklist.contract_signed %></li>
        <li><%= checklist.contract_details %></li>
        <li>…</li>
      </ul>
      <%= f.submit "Update", class: 'btn' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  ```
- app/controllers/checklists_controller.rb

  ```
  class ChecklistsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def create
      @account = Account.find(params[:account_id])
      @checklist = @account.checklist.build(params[:checklist])
      @checklist.user = current_user

      respond_to do |format|
        if @checklist.save
          format.html { redirect_to(@account, :notice => 'Checklist Saved.') }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to(@account, :notice => 'There was an errors') }
        end
      end
    end


    def destroy
      @checklist = current_user.checklists.find(params[:id])
      @account = Account.find(params[:account_id])
      @checklist.destroy

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @account }
      end
    end
  end
  ```

Comment: I think the problem is @checklist is nil

Comment: I understand it is nil. I'm not sure how to fix it since it will always be nil until it is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your view logic, but I think what you need to be doing is building the checklist before you get to the create section of the controller.

e.g.

```
  def show
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    @checklist = @account.build_checklist
  end
```

This will allow you to call the attributes in the view you are displaying.

You can also adjust the create method to, using new instead of build

```
def create
  @account = Account.find(params[:account_id])
  @checklist = @account.checklist.new(params[:checklist])
  @checklist.user = current_user

  respond_to do |format|
      if @checklist.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@account, :notice => 'Checklist Saved.') }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to(@account, :notice => 'There was an error saving your comment (empty comment or comment way to long).') }
      end
  end
end
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Ok...that makes sense. I've made the changes. Getting an error Showing : line #4 raised:

undefined method `checklists_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f9e354455b8>:0x007f9e395276d0>

Comment: do you have accepts nested attributes set on your Account class?